# jquery dropzone.js com verificação de arquivo duplicado utilizando md5

Tags: jquery, md5, dropzonejs

Se utilizar uma verificação simples no evento "addedfile" do componente "dropzone" ele funciona normalmente, enviando um arquivo, ou adicionando vários um de cada vez e também selecionando vários e enviando de uma vez só.

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
        if (this.files.length) {
            var _i, _len;
            for (_i = 0, _len = this.files.length; _i < _len - 1; _i++) // -1 to exclude current file
            {
                if (this.files[_i].name === file.name && this.files[_i].size === file.size && this.files[_i].lastModifiedDate.toString() === file.lastModifiedDate.toString())
                {
                    alert('O arquivo ' + file.name + ' já foi enviado');
                    this.removeFile(file);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Mas ao tentar implementar utilizando md5 para verificar os arquivos funciona se enviar apenas um arquivo, ou enviando um por um, mas se seleciono vários e envio de uma vez não funciona.

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
        if (this.files.length) {
            var _i, _len;
            for (_i = 0, _len = this.files.length; _i < _len - 1; _i++) // -1 to exclude current file
            {
                /**
                 * Cria um hash do arquivo e compara
                 */
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsBinaryString(this.files[_i]);
                reader.onload = function () {
                    var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(btoa(reader.result)));
                    var reader2 = new FileReader();
                    reader2.readAsBinaryString(file);
                    reader2.onload = function () {
                        var hash2 = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(btoa(reader2.result)));
                        if (hash.toString() === hash2.toString()) {
                            alert('O arquivo ' + file.name + ' já adicionado foi na lista');
                            myDropzone.removeFile(file);
                        }
                    };
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

Queria verificar se há algum arquivo duplicado utilizando md5.

Comment: Verificando o arquivo antes de utilizar o MD5 funcionou normalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O processo para verificar utilizando md5 é muito demorado, então verifique primeiro o tamanho para depois utilizar o md5.